# How to iterate a nested object using map function?

Tags: javascript

I had used for loop to iterate nested objects, I am  trying to replace `forEach` with the `map` function, without success. Can anyone help me with this?

schema.js

```js
const products_schema = {

    product_name: {
        auto: false,
        type: "string",
        min: 5,
        max: 10,
        special_characters: ['_', ' '],
        numbers: true,
        alphabet: true,
        required: true,
        correct: ""
    },
    product_image: {
        auto: false,
        type: "array:string",
        min: 0,
        max: 50,
        required: true
    }
}

const specification_schema = {
    brand: {
        auto: false,
        type: "string",
        min: 10,
        max: 50,
        special_characters: ['_', ' '],
        numbers: true,
        alphabet: true,
        required: true
    }
}

let schema = {
    products_schema:products_schema,
    specification_schema:specification_schema
}
for(var key in schema)
{
    var value = schema[key]
    Object.keys(value).forEach(key => console.log(value[key].type));
}
```

"Expected output:"
string
array:string
string

Comment: What's wrong with `for` loop?

Comment: `Object.keys(schema).map(key=> {
 var value = schema[key]
 Object.keys(value).forEach(key => console.log(value[key].type));

})`

Comment: for loop works fine. But my requirement is to replace for with map

Comment: What is the expected value of `schema`?

Comment: , expected error in your code @Harish

Comment: @hariprasanth those are two lines of code `var value = schema[key]; ` and `Object.keys(value).forEach(key => console.log(value[key].type));`

Comment: sorry, couldn't get your question@NikhilAggarwal

Comment: Thanks @GrafiCodeStudio its working fine

Answer (score 3):

use `Object.values` then use `map` to return only `type` property.

```js
const products_schema = {

    product_name: {
        auto: false,
        type: "string",
        min: 5,
        max: 10,
        special_characters: ['_', ' '],
        numbers: true,
        alphabet: true,
        required: true,
        correct: ""
    },
    product_image: {
        auto: false,
        type: "array:string",
        min: 0,
        max: 50,
        required: true
    }
}

const specification_schema = {
    brand: {
        auto: false,
        type: "string",
        min: 10,
        max: 50,
        special_characters: ['_', ' '],
        numbers: true,
        alphabet: true,
        required: true
    }
}

let schema = {
    products_schema:products_schema,
    specification_schema:specification_schema
}

const mergedObjects = {...products_schema, ...specification_schema};

const output = Object.values(mergedObjects).map(({type}) => type);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Won't work if `products_schema` and `specification_schema` have a common key

Answer (score 2):

You could use nested [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```js
const products_schema={product_name:{auto:false,type:"string",min:5,max:10,special_characters:['_',' '],numbers:true,alphabet:true,required:true,correct:""},product_image:{auto:false,type:"array:string",min:0,max:50,required:true}},
    specification_schema={brand:{auto:false,type:"string",min:10,max:50,special_characters:['_',' '],numbers:true,alphabet:true,required:true}},
    schema={ products_schema, specification_schema }

Object.values(schema).forEach(o => {
  Object.values(o).forEach(a => console.log(a.type))
})
```

If you want to get an array of nested `type` you could use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```js
const products_schema={product_name:{auto:false,type:"string",min:5,max:10,special_characters:['_',' '],numbers:true,alphabet:true,required:true,correct:""},product_image:{auto:false,type:"array:string",min:0,max:50,required:true}},
    specification_schema={brand:{auto:false,type:"string",min:10,max:50,special_characters:['_',' '],numbers:true,alphabet:true,required:true}},
    schema={ products_schema, specification_schema }

const types = Object.values(schema).flatMap(o => 
  Object.values(o).map(a => a.type)
)

console.log(types)
```

If `flatMap` is not supported, you could simply use the first snippet and `push` to an array instead of logging it to the console.

```
const output = [];

Object.values(schema).forEach(o => 
  Object.values(o).forEach(a => output.push(a.type))
)
```

Comment: flatMap is not an function error while running the code

Comment: @hariprasanth updated the answer. If `flatMap` is not supported, you can use the first snippet and `push` each `type` to an array