# Right way to iterate nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi all I have following [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-fire-hf8qp)

I am using ReactJS.

I am trying to filter from my `zipCode` file that zip code object which one user will provide in input. That filtering logic was working good, but I can't to save my object in variable becouse I am doing something wrong.

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56441856/how-to-iterate-a-nested-object-using-map-function) article but it didn't help me.

In this case I can see object when doing console log.

```
       Object.values(zipWithLocation).forEach((o) => {
        Object.values(o).forEach((second) => console.log("second", second));
       });
```

But I need to implement it in this way

```
      const first = Object.values(zipWithLocation).forEach((o) => {
         Object.values(o).forEach((a) => {
          return a;
        });
      });

     console.log("first", first);
```

But in this way it console log `undefined`.

Please help me fix the last example. It would help me to implement the following.

```
    return(
       <>
        <p>
         city -{first.City}, location: {first.State}
        <p>
        <p>{first.Delivery}</p>
        <p>please provide address: {first.Address} </p>
      </>
    )
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want? But I can see that you are trying to reduce numbers coming from input with a object bracket at the end. What do you want from that filtered variable

Comment: I want to see my output when doing `console.log("first", first);`

Comment: when i type in `144` in the input this is the output of filtered if you console.log `Object { 144: undefined }`

Comment: Try `2101` ... `144` didn't include in `zipCode` file.
When you input 2101 you can see `first undefined` and `second [object]` .... second one is working in right way, it's interesting for me how to fix `first`

Comment: first will be undefined because Array.forEach always returns undefined.

Comment: In looking at your additional code, you are using reduce wrong (it just returns what your input is, but inside an object).  If you do [someObject].reduce(...) it will just iterate once, with someObject as the element, so it seems pointless.  Same with [filtered].map.  It iterates once and you get filtered as the element.

Comment: Can you please edit my code ?, it will be better for understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since zipCodefromInput should be a key of zipCode, you can get a reference to the data by zipCode[zipCodefromInput] (no looping needed).

Try

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import zipCode from "./zipCodes";

export default function App() {
  const [zipCodefromInput, setZipCodeFromInput] = useState();

  if (zipCodefromInput in zipCode) {
    let first = zipCode[zipCodefromInput][0];
    console.log(first.City);
  } else {
    console.log("entered zip code not found in list");
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        placeholder="2101"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setZipCodeFromInput(+e.target.value);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @James, the mystery was solved :D ...

Answer (score 0):

[`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) does not return anything (hence `undefined`), you probably want to look at using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) if you want to assign the array to a variable.

For your case it seems like [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) would best fit your needs since it traverses the array and stops at the first matching condition.

```js
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

const firstB = array.find((item, index) => {
  console.log('item:', item, 'index:', index)
  return item === 'b'
});
console.log('firstB', firstB);

const forEachResult = array.forEach((item) => { return item; });
console.log('forEachResult', forEachResult);

const mapResult = array.map((item) => {return item});
console.log('mapResult', mapResult);
```